# How to Decode the Encoded value?

Tags: asp.net, encoding, decoding

Now am looking after my Friend's Project. In that project my friend encoded some value and store it in Database. Now I need to Use those values. So, I have to decode them. I Don't know where to start it...can anyone help me.

Given the Encoding method :

```
    string strmsg = string.Empty;
    byte[] encode = new byte[Text.Length];
    encode = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Text);
    strmsg = Convert.ToBase64String(encode);
```

Text is the string which is encoded here.

Note : I Need to decode the **"strmsg"** value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should decode your strmsg back to your text.

```
     byte[] decode = Convert.FromBase64String(strmsg); //strmsg is the encoded text
    strmsg  = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decode); //this strmsg is your decoded original text
```